# Why would a replacement .DLL not be found?

Tags: c#, dll, deployment, windows-ce, typeloadexception

I made a change to an ancillary DLL that my project uses, built it of course, renamed the legacy DLL to *.dll_old, and copy and pasted in the new version of the DLL to that same folder.

However, when I then ran the app that uses the DLL, it errored out with:

```
"An expected error has occurred...bla bla bla...or select Details for more information.
```

I did select Details, and saw:

```
TypeLoadException
File or assembly name <name of the DLL, which I just replaced>
Version=<bla>
Culture=neutral
PublicKeyToken=null, or one of its dependencies, was not found.
```

### UPDATE

Based on the comments, I guess there's more to replacing a DLL than one might expect. I don't know if this is significant or not, I thought replacing a DLL would be like replacing an EXE, but maybe not: the DLL project's AssemblyInfo.cs says,

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.3.*")]                // used by .NET framework only
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.3.0.308")]        // File Version - increment here
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("6.3.0")]   // Product version - set to current IEQ system
```

...and the Version in the err msg is "1.3.3889.27539"

Do I need to update one of these lines (I would guess the middle one, if so) to that value (1.3.3889.27539)? Or...???

### UPDATE

So since the .DLL is not strongly named, I tried simply removing the reference (to the old .DLL) in the project that uses the DLL and then adding it back again (same file name, different version). I see, though, that updating the .DLL does not change the version numbers shown above - IOW, the AssemblyInfo.cs does not get updated when building. Should it? Do I need to manually update these vals?

Comment: the bla bla bla part could be interesting

Comment: Have you removed the reference to the DLL and re-added it?

Comment: Have you added a new reference in the DLL and or changed a reference DLL version (i.e. you've compiled the new DLL against a different version of .net for example)?

Comment: @Peter: All down but 9, pard; set 'em up again. All I did was replace the DLL in the folder. Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: @David: The only thing I did in the DLL was add a few calls to MessageBox.Show() (that's how I have to debug this thing).

Comment: @Vlade Divac: I doubt it; the elided/omitted part was, "in HHS.exe. Select Quit and then restart this program,"

Comment: Can you make it more clear what version information applies to the old DLL and what version information applies to the new DLL?  Can you also make it clear if the old DLL or the new DLL are strongly named? http://blog.codingoutloud.com/2010/03/13/three-ways-to-tell-whether-an-assembly-dl-is-strong-named/

Comment: @Pete: the version information shown is what's in the only version of the DLL project's AssemblyInfo.cs

As to strongly named, since I don't know what you mean by that, probably not; but then again, who knows - maybe the original developer did do that...how would I know/check that? 

...now I know why people talk about ".DLL Dallas"

Comment: @Clay The link in my previous comment describes the process to determine whether or not your DLL is strongly named.  Strongly named DLLs provide additional checks to make sure they weren't changed.

Comment: Okay, I got "...does not represent a strongly named assembly."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that types inside your original DLL were referenced by your EXE file. WHen you replaced it with your own version the references were messed. The EXE file contains metadata table with a list of types, methods, properties, etc that it references and exact version of the assemble expected. Providing something else even if everything was the same but the version number is simply not the same thing. That is why you are getting the exception.

UPDATE: Yes it is possible. However it involves creating a manifest file. For more information check this MSDN web site on [Redirecting Assembly Versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Also, keep in mind that only strongly signed assemblies can be redirected. Non-signed assemblies will be ignored.

Comment: That's definitely true (types inside the DLL are referenced by the EXE). So is there a way to update the EXE's metadata table (that doesn't involve the sacrificing of chickens)?